# Extended string, casting to datatype

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I'm having a Dictionary, and I would like to cast it to current datatype for class in the loop.

```
public static T ToClass<T>(this IDictionary<string, string> source) where T : class, new()
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    T ret = new T();

    foreach (var keyValue in source)
    {
      type.GetProperty(keyValue.Key).SetValue(ret, keyValue.Value.ToNullable<T>(), null);
    }

    return ret;
}

public static Nullable<T> ToNullable<T>(this string s) where T : struct
{
    Nullable<T> result = new Nullable<T>();
    try
    {
       if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
       {
          TypeConverter conv = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
          result = (T)conv.ConvertFrom(s);
       }
     }
     catch { }
     return result;
}
```

Not sure howto make `keyValue.Value.ToNullable<T>()` to work, I want it to cast it to the datatype for the current property in the loop.

How is that done in this example?

---

I've tried this code, cant get it to work.

```
public static T TestParse<T>(this string value)
{
    return (T)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)).ConvertFromString(value);
}
```

Comment: Your ToNullable is using the T type which is not correct, being the type of the target class containing all the properties. You should use the type of each property (which unfortunately you don't have in the dictionary).

Comment: You have an example of making it a non-nullable conversion method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
/// <summary>
/// ClassExtensions
/// </summary>
static class ClassExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts an object to nullable.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="P">The object type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="s">The object value.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Nullable<P> ToNullable<P>(this string s) where P : struct
    {
        Nullable<P> result = new Nullable<P>();
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
            {
                TypeConverter conv = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(P));
                result = (P)conv.ConvertFrom(s);
            }
        }
        catch { }
        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a dictionary of property values into a class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The class type.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="source">The properties dictionary.</param>
    /// <returns>An instance of T with property values set to the values defined in the dictionary.</returns>
    public static T ToClass<T>(this IDictionary<string, string> source) where T : class, new()
    {
        Type classType = typeof(T);
        T returnClass = new T();

        foreach (var keyValue in source)
        {
            PropertyInfo prop = classType.GetProperty(keyValue.Key);

            MethodInfo method = typeof(ClassExtensions).GetMethod("ToNullable");
            MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(prop.PropertyType);
            object convertedValue = generic.Invoke(keyValue.Value, new object[] { keyValue.Value });

            prop.SetValue(returnClass, convertedValue, null);
        }

        return returnClass;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// TestClass
/// </summary>
class TestClass
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public long Property2 { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Program.
/// </summary>
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> properties = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Property1", "1" }, { "Property2", "2" } };
        properties.ToClass<TestClass>();
    }
}
```